# Nokia Lumia 520 Radio doesn't work

Tags: lumia

I bought a Lumia 520 a few days ago and am pleased with it. But, the radio doesn't work at all well.  I'm using the headphones that came with it, and realise they have to be plugged in to work as an antenae. But, I can hardly get any stations at all and everything just sounds like snow. I'm using it in the same places I used to use my old android phone, where I always had brilliant reception. I've read about an amber update improving performance, but this is a new phone, so surely shouldn't need the update? Any suggestions welcome.

Comment: Can you check which OS and firmware version your phone has? From the Start screen, swipe right, scroll down to Settings, tap on it, find "extras+info", tap on it and see what it reports as "Software release".

Comment: There's not a "software release"option, but it says that the firmware update notifier is 1.0.1.7 and application version 3.0.6.1

Comment: Ah, sorry looked again, Lumia Black is listed under software release.

Comment: Just tried the Radio (FM Radio in 8.1) and it works fine for me on a Lumia 520, can you try a different pair of headphones and different locations?

Comment: What regions do you get to select?